# Stop training model when accuracy reached greater than 0.99

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to stop my model from getting trained after it reaches a certain threshold. I have written a class for a callback from Tensorflow. I'm training the MNIST dataset. To categorize the handwritten numbers and identify. But for some reason, the training is not getting stopped. I can't find a reason. Here is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.99):
      print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
      self.model.stop_training = True

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

callbacks = myCallback()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[callbacks])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class StopOnPoint(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, point):
        super(StopOnPoint, self).__init__()
        self.point = point

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None): 
        accuracy = logs["accuracy"]
        if accuracy >= self.point:
            self.model.stop_training = True

callbacks = [StopOnPoint(0.98)] # <- set optimal point
```